# SignOut is not working when calling after PasswordSignIn?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

In ASP.NET Identity I am have,

```
var result = await _userManager.PasswordSignIn(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, true);
if(result == SignInStatus.Success)
{
    if (myCondition)
    {
        _userManager.SignOut();
    }
}
```

Here the SignOut is not working. Means user is logged-in.

Comment: What could be the possible use of that?

Comment: How about `if(!mycondition) await _userManager.PasswordSignin(...)`?

Comment: @trailmax, for now I am doing the same. But the question is that why it doesn't work.

Comment: @user960567 ah, I see. See my attempt in answering, not sure if that will help though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is a bug in Katana, which I believe will be fixed in the aspnet vNext update, the basic issue is that when you are calling both SignIn and SignOut in the same request, the logical assumption is that the last one wins.  I believe today, its either only the first one, or SignIn always wins over SignOut.

The issue was tracked here [Katana codeplex issue](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/workitem/201)

Answer (score 2):

I presume you use `SignInManager` in Identity v2.1 as there is no such method on `UserManager`.

When you call `SignInManaer.PasswordSignIn()`, after a number of checks, if everything is successful,  auth-cookie is not actually set; it only sets a callback for later, when it actually comes time for sending HTTP reply.

When you call `SignOut()` `AuthenticationManager` checks if there was a sign-in granted before, but it also checks if types of SignIn `AuthenticationType` matches the types of `SignOut`. I'm guessing your sign-in is using different auth types to sign-out.

There are too many possible ways why this does not work. Without looking on the whole solution it is hard to deduce the cause.

[You can check out `AuthenticationManager` from Owin in Katana Project](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin/Security/AuthenticationManager.cs) and see for yourself what exactly is going wrong - this component is actually used by Identity to set callbacks in Owin to create (or remove) auth-cookies.

I can only think of using this for sign-out:

```
AuthenticationManager.SignOut(
    DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,
    DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie,
    DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie,
    DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer);
```

Sign-out from everything. Just to be sure -)

Answer (score 1):

UserManager is

```
private ApplicationUserManager userManager;
        public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
        {
            get
            {
                return userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            }
            private set
            {
                userManager = value;
            }
        }
```

but the sign out need to use AuthenticationManager which is

```
private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        }
    }
```

Sign out should be

```
AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
```

Not UserManger.

Hope this helps.